# Clickable link in draggable node in angular-ui-tree

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-tree

In [angular-ui-tree](https://github.com/angular-ui-tree/angular-ui-tree) I'm looking for a way to have links inside a draggable node.

What's happening now is that when I click on the link inside the node it starts "holding" the whole node to drag it.

I saw this answer [Angular JS (angular-ui-tree) ng-click conflict vs drag start event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27088636/angular-js-angular-ui-tree-ng-click-conflict-vs-drag-start-event), however it is not similar to what I want to do. In this answer `ng-click` is bound to the node, where in my case I have multiple links inside the node.

Below is my html:

```
    <div ui-tree="treeOptions" drag-delay="1000" id="tree-root">
      <ol ui-tree-nodes ng-model="filteredModules" data-nodrop>
        <li ng-repeat="module in filteredModules" ui-tree-node>
          <div ui-tree-handle ng-click="toggle(this)">
            <a class="btn btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-right': collapsed, 'glyphicon-chevron-down': !collapsed}"></span></a>
                {{module.name}}
          </div>
          <ol ui-tree-nodes ng-model="module.stages" data-nodrop ng-class="{hidden: collapsed}">
            <li ng-repeat="stage in module.stages" ui-tree-node>
              <div ui-tree-handle ng-click="toggle(this)">
                <a class="btn btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-right': collapsed, 'glyphicon-chevron-down': !collapsed}"></span></a>
                    {{stage.name}}
              </div>
              <div ui-tree-nodes ng-model="stage.cases" ng-class="{hidden: collapsed}">
                  <div ng-repeat="case in stage.cases" ui-tree-node>
                  <div ui-tree-handle>

                    <!-- HERE I HAVE TWO LINKS -->

                    <a href="/#/admin/cases/{{case._id}}">{{case.name}}</a>                       
                    <a href="/#/admin/cases/edit/{{case._id}}" class="pull-right btn btn-primary btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> Edit</a>                 
                  </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </li>
          </ol>
        </li>
      </ol>
    </div>
```

Is there a way to have multiple links inside a draggable node?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the no-drag attribute to the links like this:

```
<a data-nodrag href="/#/admin/cases/{{case._id}}">{{case.name}}</a>                       
<a data-nodrag href="/#/admin/cases/edit/{{case._id}}" class="pull-right btn btn-primary btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> Edit</a>
```

Comment: Wow! thanks for the magic answer. I tried all sort of stuff, didn't know it is that simple. The [documentation](https://github.com/angular-ui-tree/angular-ui-tree#data-nodrag) mentions this attribute for the node but not for tags inside the node. Thanks again

Comment: but i need to drag and also need perform some action on that click means selected node prop...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. This is how I fixed it:

Add the  `a`  element in line number 602 of angular-ui-tree.js

```
eventElmTagName = eventElm.prop('tagName').toLowerCase();
if (eventElmTagName == 'input' ||
eventElmTagName == 'textarea' ||
eventElmTagName == 'button' ||
eventElmTagName == 'i' ||
eventElmTagName == 'a' ||  //this would ignore 'a' elements while dragging
eventElmTagName == 'select') { 
return;
}
```

Just an FYI - you are using glyphicons in the `span` element. So you might face the same problem if you click on the glyphicon. Add `span` element in the above statement to fix that as well.