# angular-ui-tree click doesn't work

Tags: angularjs

I downloaded the angular-ui-tree package and installed it in a webserver. I can bring up the example pages fine in my browser, but all the click actions on the buttons (to collapse/expand the tree, add node etc) do not work. I don't get any errors in firebug.
If I point my browser at the public page for the tree component ( https://jimliu.github.io/angular-ui-tree/index.html) it does work.

I did some debugging and found that the problem is when ng-repeat is called for a ui-tree-node element, an ng-click action does not work.
In the code below, the test() function is in my controller and it gets executed if I remove the ui-tree-node or ng-repeat tags.

```
<li ui-tree-node ng-repeat="node in mydata" > 
    <a  ng-click="test()" >{{node.title}} </a>
</li>
```

Is this a bug in angular tree component?
Is there some way I can fix this in my environment?

Comment: try adding `<li ui-tree-node data-drag-delay="100" ng-repeat="node in mydata" > "`

Answer (score 4):

The fix was to add the data-nodrag tag in the top level ui-tree-nodes element.

(adding data-nodrag in the li element also works).

Comment: you mean to say that drag and onclick can't be used together?

Comment: I also had issues with click + drag, but worked it around. See details here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27088636/angular-js-angular-ui-tree-ng-click-conflict-vs-drag-start-event/37527842#37527842

Answer (score 0):

You can use both:

- click with toggle(this)
- drag

together, just make sure that the element to expand/collapse ist not within the ui-tree-handle

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="tree_renderer.html">
  <div ng-class="{collapsed: collapsed}">
    <div class="ctx_node" 
        ui-on-drop="onDrop($event, $data, ctx,node); active=false"> 
        <span class="expanded" 
            ng-click="toggle(this)"
            ng-class="{'collapsed': collapsed,'expanded': !collapsed}">
        </span>
        <span ui-tree-handle>{{node.title}}</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <ol ui-tree-nodes="" ng-model="node.nodes">
    <li ng-repeat="node in node.nodes" 
        ui-tree-node ng-include="'tree_renderer.html'">
    </li>
  </ol>
</script>
<div ui-tree data-drag-enabled>
  <ol ui-tree-nodes="" ng-model="node.nodes" id="tree-root">
    <li ng-repeat="node in node.nodes" 
        ui-tree-node ng-include="'tree_renderer.html'"></li>
  </ol>
</div>
```